# Open set and metric space problem: Isn't it trivial?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I am trying to prove the following:

> Let (M, d) be a metric space. Let $S \subset M$ be open. For each 
>   $x \in S$ let $\epsilon > 0$ be such that $B(x, \epsilon_x) \subset S$.
>   Prove that $$S = \cup_{x \in S} B (x, \epsilon_x)$$

I am planning to prove it in two steps.

1. $\forall x \in S : B(x, \epsilon_x) \subset S$ - this is true by the definition of the problem.
2. $\forall a \in S : a \in \cup_{x \in S} B(x, \epsilon_x)$ - this is true because from the definition, $B(a, \epsilon_a) \subset S$

Am I doing it right?

Comment: Yes, you're doing it right.

Comment: The key fact is that for each $x\in S$, there really is such an $\epsilon_x$, because $S$ is open. Your step 2 is perhaps a little unclear. We have that $a$ is an element of the union because $a\in B(a,\epsilon_a)$.